# Is there a way to get the absolute path of a google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to get the absolute path of a google chrome extension? Any idea, thought, is very welcome!.

**EDIT**

I build a plugin using Firebreath and i need to know where my extension is locate because i would like to call myExecutable.

Folder:

```
myExtensionFolder/
     manifest.json
     background.html
     background.js
     popup.html
     popup.js
     **myExecutable**
```

TIA.

**Solution**

Solved the problem. I was using a symbolic link to myExecutable file. I copy the file directly to my folder solves the problem.

Anyways, thanks guys for your answers.

Comment: Absolute path where? On disk?

Comment: I edited my question for clarification. @MДΓΓБДLL, Yes, that could it be.

Comment: If you have solved your own issue, post a long and detailed answer how you found it. It'll help people for future reference, and you might get a few REP points for it and maybe a badge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

Solved the problem. I was using a symbolic link to myExecutable file. I copy the file directly to my folder solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inside chrome, it's `chrome-extension://your-extension-id-here/whateverfile.html`, obtainable via [`chrome.extension.getURL("whateverfile.html")`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL). On disk, it's the Extensions folder in your [user profile](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=142059).